How Null Characters and Uninitialized Memory Affect Output in C++ Arrays
The null character in char type array affects the output.
I learned that after inputting a string into a char array, there is a null character added at the end of the input. The cout function will automatically stop printing when it encounters a null character. However, I replaced the null character at index 3 (which was initially there) with the character 'd' and set index 4 to 'e'. As a result, the output of my program is dogde followed by random characters until the end of the array size. For example, it prints dogdeâ€™â€™â€™â€™â€™â€™ until the end of the array size. My teacher's result shows that the null character was placed at index 7 after two random characters were added at index 5 and 6.
Here are my questions:
Why doesn't the null character get added automatically after the character 'e' (index 4), and why does the output include random characters until the end of the array size?
Do other array types automatically get null values assigned if we don't use the full size of the array? As far as I know, values are set to 0 for other data types, so why is it different for char arrays?
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char array[10];
    cin >> array;
    cout << "Ket qua la " << array;
    int i = 0;
    while (array[i] != '\0' && i < 10)\
    {
        i++;
    }
    if (i < 9)
    {
        cout << endl << i;
    }
    cout << endl << "Sau do" << endl;
    array[i] = 'd';
    array[i + 1] = 'e';
    cout << array;
}


'e'  is a char litteral, not a string, it represents one character (btw, '\0' or simply 0, represents the null character) . A string litteral like "Ket qua la" is supposed to represent a string, hence an array of the same characters followed by an additional null character.

It's the convention for strings, not for other types.

In C++ you should generally use std::string unless you need to interface with C libraries that need C strings.

Like you say, cout will stop printing when it hits the nul character, So if you remove that, it will not stop printing. That's all there is to it! And no, arrays are not given values unless the program says so. The difference is that you don't send other whole arrays to cout , only char arrays.

Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that std::endl does. Use '\n' to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.

"why does the output include random characters..." Because it is undefined behavior tou output a char arryay that don't have a null terminator. "Undefined behavior means anything can happen including but not limited to the program giving your expected output. But never rely on the output of a program that has UB. The program may just crash."

"Why doesn't the null character get added automatically..." Because char array[10] leaves the array uninitialized so assuming it should have a null character is wrong.

"As far as I know, values are set to 0 for other data types..." That is a wrong assumption.

"so why is it different for char arrays?..." It is not. The array is uninitialized. Uninitialized Array in C programming


Why doesn't the null character get added automatically after the character 'e' (index 4)

Noone has put forward this proposal to the C++ Commitee. If anyone did, I'm pretty sure it would get shut down quickly since most people don't want other elements to change when changing an element in an array.

why does the output include random characters until the end of the array size?

array starts out with indeterminate values since you haven't initialized it.
After you've entered a word, say Hi!, in std::cin >> array, only 4 elements will be initialized in array. H, i, !, \0 and the rest of the bytes are still indeterminate. They could be anything - which is what you see as "random characters" when you print array. Also note that there is no guarantee that there will be a \0 in array after you've removed the first one, so printing it could cause the printing routine to read out of bounds which could crash your program (or worse).
Example of initialization:
char array[10]{}; // Example of an array initialized with all `\0`


Do other array types automatically get null values assigned if we don't use the full size of the array?

Local variables of fundamental types, like char and int, will not. That includes arrays of such types. It also includes classes of such types where the classes don't initialize them upon construction. If you want them initialized, you must do it explicitly.

As far as I know, values are set to 0 for other data types, so why is it different for char arrays?

No, that's wrong. If you don't initialize them, they are left indeterminate.
